# How to determine the partition on which Ubuntu is installed and resize it?

Tags: partitioning, wubi

I have four partitions on my hard-drive: C, E, F and G. Partitions C and G are NTFS and I installed Ubuntu using Wubi through Windows 7. Probably I installed it on the partition G, where Windows 7 is also installed. I guess I created a new partition within G for Ubuntu and it was a minimum 3.5 GB installation.

From Ubuntu, I want to check on which partition I installed it and how much space is left. How to do this? I also want to install any Ubuntu package that can resize the partition by taking the free space from another partition.

Answer (score 1):

Wubi does not install Ubuntu into a real partition but instead resides in some files on your NTFS partition. I can't really say how you can find out where your files are located but you might be interested in [Wubi: How do I resize the virtual disks?](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How%20do%20I%20resize%20the%20virtual%20disks?).

Answer (score 1):

It's probably simplest to mount each partition in turn and look for a filesystem containing an `ubuntu/disks` directory.

Answer (score 0):

The following commands show how to determine the host partition, and the space used:

```
bcbc@ubuntu:~$ mount | grep '/host'
/dev/sda3 on /host type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)
bcbc@ubuntu:~$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0            5.0G  4.0G  739M  85% /
none                  494M  672K  493M   1% /dev
none                  501M  336K  500M   1% /dev/shm
none                  501M  256K  500M   1% /var/run
none                  501M     0  501M   0% /var/lock
/dev/sda3              20G   12G  8.0G  60% /host
```

In the above, my host partition is /dev/sda3 and the space remaining on the virtual disk (/dev/loop0) is 739MB, the space remaining on /host is 8GB.

You cannot determine the "drive designation" that Windows uses for /dev/sda3 from within Wubi. But if you go to Windows, then the drive will contain the "ubuntu" folder in the root. e.g. G:\ubuntu

For resizing the virtual disks, please refer to the [Wubi Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How%20do%20I%20resize%20the%20virtual%20disks?)