# Installed windows 8 alongwith existing ubuntu 13.04 ubuntu grub not installing

Tags: 13.04, grub2, windows-8, boot-repair

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6214502/

i previously had windows 7 and ubuntu 13.04 dual boot ..working perfectly..
then i did a clean installation of windows 8 over my win7
partition..it succeeded .(by disabling the Uefi option in bios)
then i tried boot-repair x64 disk of ubuntu to repair ..but it didnt
installed grub ..
moreover grub options in the advanced tab (of the repair disk utility)
are disabled
how can i force install grub on sda..or any other way

Answer (score 2):

Installing Grub manually is fairly simple, and once you get it, there shouldn't be anything keeping you from dual-booting successfully.

First, boot the computer up off of your standard Ubuntu installation disk. You should be using the same version (e.g. 13.04) and the same architechture (e.g. amd64, 64-Bit) as your currently installed Ubuntu. If you need to download an old version, you can do so at [http://releases.ubuntu.com](http://releases.ubuntu.com/).

Once you've booted the disk up, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal window. In that, type in the following commands:

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolve.conf
```

Note that that last command may fail if you aren't connected to the network. It isn't strictly necessary, so if running it gives you an error, you can simply ignore it.

Also, you may need to replace `/dev/sda1` with something else, depending on the hard disk partition you have Ubuntu installed on. You can get help with determining the exact line in [This Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167015/how-to-find-out-which-partition-is-ubuntu-installed-on).

Once you've done all of that, we're ready to proceed. In the terminal, enter in this command:

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

You'll see the prompt in the terminal change from `ubuntu@ubuntu:~$` to something like `root@ubuntu:~#`. It may be different for your specific machine. This tells us we're ready to install grub. Run this command to do it:

```
grub-install --force /dev/sda
```

Once you're finished with this, reboot your computer. It should boot back up into Ubuntu.

Next we need to add an entry for Windows 8 into Grub, and remove any Windows 7 entries that are still there. To do this, open another terminal window, then enter this command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

This command will take a minute or two, then you're all set. If you reboot your computer, you should be prompted to boot either Ubuntu or Windows 8.