# ubuntu 14.04 black screen when installing

Tags: boot, system-installation

I'm new in this forum.

I know, that this is an old problem and I have been reading other questions regarding this. However, I've been unable to find the solution.

I've been trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my Asus Vivobook F200MA machine from USB, but the screen goes black, if I choose any of the options. It is a new machine, with only freedos on it.

If I follow the instructions on

[My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

it still doesn't work.

SATA is set to AHCI,
Secure Boot is disabled,
CSM is enabled.

Do you have any ideas, how I could install it?

**Edit:**

I have tried:

- checking the usb for errors (no errors),
- verified the integrity (alright),
- disabled the secure boot
- enabled csm
- set SATA to AHCI from the menu (try without installing, install and
  check for defects) because the screen goes black.

Comment: What have you done of the suggestions? You should try the `nomodset` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, I've tried it, but I can't access ubuntu live cd, the screen goes black as well.

Comment: Same problem for me with Ubuntu 16.04 and my ASUS z170 motherboard.

Comment: Same problem with Ubuntu 18.04 and Compaq Deskpro En but the same CD works on a P3 256Mb Dell.

Answer (score 17):

I had this problem and solved using the **nomodeset** mentioned by @Xubu-Tur along with the **nolapic**. This last one was necessary otherwise it woudn't work, but I am assuming you can get to the installation window (it is not clear in your question), like shown below:

[image]

**EDIT:**

I see. I think the options beneath allow you to edit the boot parameters. If that is the case, then you can set the boot parameters adding "nomodeset" and "nolapic" to the same place of the "quiet" and "splash". In the end it should be something like `(...) quiet splash nomodeset nolapic (...)`. In the [link you provided](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) in the question there is an example (the guy removed the quiet splash, but I don't think that is necessary).

[image: Boot Parameters]

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear before: I can't get into this menu. All I get is menu like this

http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1347445084.png

If I understand it correctly, it is booting in EFI mode.

Comment: I updated the answer (maybe you already saw. Just add this here to document for others).

Comment: I tried writing "quiet splash nomodeset nolapic" in the boot parameters. I also tried removing "quiet splash" and replacing it with "nomodeset nolapic". It still doesn't work. However, now it shows commands running for a split second, but then restarts and goes to black screen. 

Is it possible that I replaced wrong? I left one space between each parameter (nomodeset nolapic) and did not delete any of the "--" after the parameters..

Comment: Try to include one more option: `acpi=off`. Regarding the spaces you got it right. So now it should be `(...) quiet splash acpi=off nolapic nomodeset (...)`. Try in this order, just in case.

Comment: I got to the Ubuntu loading screen, but after a minute it showed me: BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system.


I verified the USB stick before, it didn't have any errors.

Comment: @altonis How did you create the bootable USB drive?

Comment: I used Universal USB installer 1.9.5.2, Ubuntu 64 bit iso and 16 Gb USB Stick. I did not change anything in the settings.

Comment: The message seems to be about your usb port. Have you tried a different one?

Comment: Yes, I tried all of them, the same result. Is it possible that parameter acpi=off also disables my usb ports? My usb stick has a light and it's off, when I boot it with acpi=off.

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not sure. If I'm not mistaken when I installed mine I also used a USB drive and didn't have this problem. But I don't know what acpi is for.

Comment: COuld it be a bios problem? I tried also installing it via external cd/dvd rom and got the same problem...

Comment: I really don't know. The only think I still haven't suggested is for you to try other distributions.

Comment: I am currently using OpeSuse 13.1, that was the only one that worked (also different Windows versions did not work, just restarted in the middle of loading files). However, I would like to change to Ubuntu. I will try registering in ASUS homepage. It is a brand new computer and I am quite frustrated, that I am not able to do the things I want with it.

Comment: Yeah.. maybe they can help. If so, post something here so we know. I had a lot of problems with Linux in my Asus but never thought of asking them. Good luck!

Comment: Hi again! I'm writing from my Ubuntu 14.04 now. I updated my bios (from 302 to 500), disabled UEFI and after that I did not have any problems. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Nice! Did you get that from Asus or was your own idea?

Comment: For me, adding nomodeset nolapic to /etc/default/grub file along with quiet splash fixed the issue also in the future startups.

Comment: Mine only worked when I removed `quiet splash` and added only `nomodeset`. When I also added `nolapic`, I'd get kernel panic.

Comment: OMG!!!!!!!!! fixed my issue!

Answer (score 3):

Add this to the kernel booting options (as specified by  marcelocra user in one of the comments):

```
quiet splash acpi=off nolapic nomodeset
```

**Important note**

Because of `nolapic` you will have only a single cpu and core visible, hence you should disable this for a later usage.

Comment: Using these options exactly worked for me with Ubuntu 16.04 and my asus z170 mobo

Comment: Where do I go and make these changes?

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem on Ubuntu 14, 15 and 16 on CD or USB but confusingly was able to install Win10 from CD.

What it turned out was the cdrom drive was connected to SATA port with AHCI - Ubuntu has a problem with that.

With `nomodeset` and splash off (so you can see where it fails) I was able to identify it to ATA problem.

Disconnecting the CD I was able to install Ubuntu 16.04 without issue (I might have had `nomodeset`).

Then reconnected it to non-AHCI SATA port after installation complete.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. What fixed it for me was to connect the monitor via VGA instead of the DVI connection that I had in place.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all advices given about that "black screen" issue after having installed properly, with no faults, the installation wizard. None of them solved my problem.

The only thing that saved my Kubuntu 14.04, after restarting from the complete installation of software, was when I ran Bios setup, went to Boot page, selected as 1st Hard Disk Drive and 1st Boot Device my HDD.

Try it for other Linux Distributions also.

None of "nomodeset", "nouveau.noaccel=1", remove of "quiet splash --", setting grub on other HDD, Bios "Quick Boot = Off" and changing live usb solved it.

Also I realized that I could not set as disk to boot other HDD than the one of my previous Linux Distribution without receiving the error "grub-install /dev/sda failed". I wanted root and home partition on sdb (larger disk) while previously was on sda (smaller disk). To solve this problem I tried many things like the advices given on these pages:

[How to find out which partition is Ubuntu installed on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167015/how-to-find-out-which-partition-is-ubuntu-installed-on)

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/11/reinstall-grub-ubuntu-wont-boot/

http://ubuntu.aspcode.net/view/635400140124705175127972/executing-grub-install-devsda5-failed-this-is-a-fatal-error

I ended using LVM on my old disk (sda), which I believe is a good solution (read about it: [What is LVM and what is it used for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3596/what-is-lvm-and-what-is-it-used-for)).
Regarding the "black screen" issue, I suggest that you should try to make as 1st Hard Disk Drive and 1st Boot Device your HDD, on Bios Menu, after completing installation wizard and see if that helps you. Nothing to lose. Solved my problem
Thank you all for the advice given!!!

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer.

Comment: Sorry, if I did not help and for the large text written above...I was just over-excited after my "Black screen problem" was solved and I thought myself obliged to tell others too, if that helps...Thank you again!

Comment: It is just really hard to read and tell where the answer is. You may want to put links used as sources near the bottom, or use asterisks maybe. It is just hard to see exactly where the answer is even though your links contain lots of useful information.

Comment: Ok...I understand now...Thanks for the advice given...I am just new on askubuntu.com...I will apply them directly on my next post, if any...Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a bit late... But I have found that when installing Ubuntu it's best to have your display set to a VGA display until the install is complete. I'm not entirely sure why but using HDMI for DVI won't display.

Answer (score 0):

Booting from USB, and using `vga=normal nomodeset` didn't help. using `nolapic` solved it!

Answer (score 0):

I have two monitors, one connected through hdmi, another through dvi. Screen went blank when monitor with hdmi was chosen to be the primary on boot by default. After I disconnected hdmi cable, Ubuntu started installation with my dvi monitor working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on an Asus GL752VW. Updating the BIOS fixed it.

With the original BIOS, it would hang on the black screen or the purple screen. The nolapic and nomodeset options would sometimes help but it was very unreliable. So I booted to Windows, downloaded and unzipped the new BIOS from http://www.asus.com/support/ then rebooted, hit F2 and navigated to the BIOS update tool to install it.

With the new BIOS installed, I reinstalled Ubuntu and everything worked perfectly without requiring the nolapic and nomodeset options.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but came across this same problem installing 16.10 desktop.

I had an external CD-ROM attached to the front USB ports and kept getting a "no signal" from monitor after selecting Install Ubuntu.

After attaching CD-ROM to the rear USB ports and rebooting, the install progressed normally.

Answer (score 0):

this one helped me: Try to include one more option: acpi=off. Regarding the spaces you got it right. So now it should be (...) quiet splash acpi=off nolapic nomodeset (...). Try in this order, just in case. –

Answer (score -1):

You should use `vga=normal nomodeset` before the `--`. That should disable the frame buffer. Removing only `quiet splash` doesn't help.

Answer (score -1):

What solved this problem on my Windows 8.1 HP notebook was enabling the "Legacy Support" option ( Power -> {SHIFT} Restart -> Troubleshoot -> Advanced Options -> UEFI Firmware Settings -> Restart-> F10 BIOS Setup -> System Configuration -> Boot Options -> Legacy Support).

I also had Fast Startup and Secure Boot turned OFF, as suggested on another very useful webpage http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html .