# boot menu shows up but Ubuntu won't work

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I am have trouble with Ubuntu's install disk. I have put  together a new pc, low cost and not too powerful but it should run Ubuntu 14.04. It currently has no OS. My problem is, when I put in the cd with Ubuntu, it show the try/install menu, but won't show any further. When go to the "try it" option , the monitor becomes black for a couple minutes without any result. please, can someone explain me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that other people have had similar problems before. Try the suggested answers in this topic

[ubuntu 14.04 black screen when installing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470492/ubuntu-14-04-black-screen-when-installing)

that basically tell you to add

```
nomodeset nolapic
```

to your boot parameters.

Comment: Please mark this as a duplicate instead of an answer

Comment: I don't have enough reputation for that