# new motherboard - can't install ubuntu

Tags: boot, system-installation

I replaced motherboard to new one AsRock Q1900DC-ITX
So I want to install new ubuntu version, I burnt DVD and connected external dvd drive via usb. Then pressing F11 to select boot drive, dvd is running purple screenis shown and then going to black screen and nothing happen.

Any ideas? Do you have any experience with asrock Q1900DC-ITX. My old motherboard worked prefectly

Comment: Try removing quiet and splash from the boot options and see if any error appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the purple screen is from the Ubuntu setup? It sounds like the system doesn't recognize a proper boot device. But you could check by pressing the arrow key to the right (actually don't really think it matters which arrow key you use) to get into the custom install menu. You can choose extra options from there making sure the screen doesn't go black. Check the link for more info.

[ubuntu 14.04 black screen when installing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470492/ubuntu-14-04-black-screen-when-installing)

Good luck!

Comment: I can see that screen https://www.logicsupply.com/explore/io-hub/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/boot_splash.png and after it goes to black screen

Comment: Please don't link to other answers on this site, but flag the question as a duplicate.....

Comment: @domos To add new information, please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/721567/edit) your question and do not just place it in comments anywhere where nobody will find it...

Answer (score 0):

I found issue - one RAM module is broken. thanks for help

Comment: @DavidFoerster This was a self-answer by the OP who found out the problem cause himself finally. Instead of voting to delete the answer, you should have rather closed the question as not reproducible because of hardware failure. (Thanks for reading! This is not to criticise you, but just to help you taking the right action next time of course.)

Comment: @ByteCommander: Alright. I've already voted to close for irreproducibility a while ago.