# Ubuntu 14.04 on Lenovo P50

Tags: 14.04, lenovo

i recently got a Lenovo P50 and tried to install Ubuntu 14.04.

But I'm always ending up in a black screen...

I tried all the things mentioned here [ubuntu 14.04 black screen when installing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470492/ubuntu-14-04-black-screen-when-installing)

but couldn't fix it.

Did someone manage to install Ubuntu 14.04 or 15.10 on an P50.

Please tell me how....

Comment: Did your P50 running with the 4K screen ?

Comment: I had a really hard time installing 15.10 next to the default Windows installed on my P50.  I eventually had to shim grub into the default {bootmgr} entry in the windows efi boot loader (using bcdedit from Windows) after "repairing" grub2 using the Super Grub2 Disk

Answer (score 0):

With Xubuntu 16.04, the experience is pretty good. 
You can expect everything to work, except the fingerprint scanner. By everything, I include Optimus, which is the most frustrating aspect. However, luckily with this class of hardware, there is a bios setting to activate discrete video, in which case you end up simply with a Nvidia laptop. 
If you need the incredibly good battery life of intel-only mode, you will need Optimus working. Note that if you are prepared to live with the non-LTS releases, there are very big advances in Optimus support available in Ubuntu 17.04 and it seems to work well with Gnome and Unity, unlike 16.04 where I recommend xfce (it has an older compositor which handles Optimus better when using the xserver we are stuck with until 16.04.3). People who try to get Gnome, KDE or Unity working on anything with xserver < 1.19 will have grief if they want two external monitors and Optimus.

I have SecureBoot off. 
I document my ongoing experience here: http://timrichardson.net/index.php/technology/linux-on-thinkpad-p50