# How can I run the 16.04 installer without using `nouveau`?

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, nouveau

I have tried installing numerous Linux distros with no luck. In every case, it appears to be due to a failure by ***`nouveau`*** driver to identify my graphics card, which is an **Nvidia GeForce GTX970M**.

My preferred distro is either ***Kubuntu*** or ***Ubuntu Studio***, but I have also tried *ArchLinux, Fedora KDE, LinuxMint, Mageia, Netrunner, and OpenSUSE*. All appear to be using ***`nouveau`*** driver, as they attempt to load up even the installer menu fails on most, stopping on a screen that looks like this:

[image]

I suspect, given what is typically shown on screen when the installation attempt stops, that the problem is with ***`nouveau`*** driver, so: is there a way to use the ***Nvidia*** proprietary drivers in the installation?

Or any other solution? A coworker suggested that I do a non-graphical, text-only install, but I have not found a way to do this that does not require making a menu choice first … but I can't see the installer menu.

Comment: You could do a minimal install from the Server ISO, and then enable the partner repository by uncommenting the line for it in /etc/apt/sources.list, then do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-desktop nvidia-current && sudo apt-get autoremove --purge ubuntu-server`. This would then install Ubuntu Studio packages, the NVidia driver, and remove the extra server packages which aren't needed.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar problem when setting up my computer with Ubuntu, which also uses the GTX970M. 
The solution I ended up using was to edit the boot parameters to include the `nouveau.modeset=0` option.

When booting into Ubuntu, press "e" while with Ubuntu selected as the boot option to edit the boot parameters.

After `quiet splash`, you should add `nouveau.modeset=0`.

You might also try `nomodeset` instead of `nouveau.modeset=0`

This thread might also help: [ubuntu 14.04 black screen when installing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470492/ubuntu-14-04-black-screen-when-installing)

Comment: After posting this question I tried some additional installations. One of these worked: OpenBSD. Thanks to all who responded, but I will stick with what I got to work, so I cannot comment on the proposed solutions. Thanks!